# Deleting a txt file using java code before creating and adding new output

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I am a novice programmer and I am trying to delete a text file from my desktop using Java from javaServlet but its not working. I have a command that creates a text file and adds output to this text file everytime but I want to delete this text file whenever the javaServlet page reloads.

```
String outputFile = "C:\\Users\\aookpidi\\Desktop\\output.txt";
try {
    File file = new File(outputFile);
    if(file.delete()){
        //System.out.println(file + " is deleted!");
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It could be a problem of permissions. How is the servlet served? Is the JVM involved running under your own user and privileges?

Comment: When you say it isn't working what do you mean? Does it throw an exception, in which case what is the stacktrace? or does it print out the message in the else-statement?

Comment: Yes it does print out the operation in the else statement "Delete operation is failed."

Comment: @Buzz first double check that the file is in fact there with the exists() method. If it is there then it's most likely a problem with the permissions.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am logged in with my credentials and I am recognised as an administrator of this host because I can download and do other things with admin login. I am not sure what you mean by how the servlet is served

Comment: 1. May be you didn't close file after writing output

Comment: A servlet is usually part of a web server, such as Tomcat or Jetty. That server may be running as a service rather than under your logged-in user, and the service may not have the same privileges as your logged-in user.

Comment: Yeah I think that the problem. I have tried exactly the same code on my home laptop in a new Java project and it deleted the file. I will have to email my boss to sort this out. thanks for the help guys

Comment: I have tried all I can but still doesn't work as I have sorted the admin full control on the File Paths. other methods work like file.canExecute() etc and it returns true. The delete works in a Java application so I think it has something to with the servlet. any suggestions please?